# Method to get to the middle of the file for Binary Search

Tags: c++, search, pointers, binary, variable-assignment

I am doing an assignment where I've got given a program which reads in a data file and spits out the data into an array of bytes, where the first 4 bytes of the array tell you how many people's names it has (the data file contains). Following the rest of the array which holds strings of the names of the people. This array is pointed to by a `const void * foo;`

For example, the first 4 bytes say there are 5 names stored into the array, and the next 4 bytes tell you the address of the person's name. The person's name is stored in the array

```
int num = ((int*)foo)[0];
const int ppl1 = ((int*)foo)[1];
string name = ((char*)foo)+ppl1;
```

so `num` would tell you theres 5 names in the array and `ppl1` would tell you the position of the array where you can find the first name and name collects the name of the person located at that slot of the array.

Pretty much, I am given a name to search for in the array, and I wanted to use binary search to doit. I don't know of a way to find the middle of the file though, can you guys give me some pointers?

cheers =]

EDIT: so I created this, but it seg faults and only works for one case (when searching for the first entry). No idea why...

```
    int first = 0;
    int num = ((int*)foo)[0];
    int last = num;


    while (first <= last) {
        int middle = first+last/2;
        int offset = ((int*)foo)[middle];
        string name = ((char*)foo)+offset;
        if (person < name) {
            last = middle-1;
        } else if (person > name) {
            first = middle+1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Binary search required the data to be sorted. Is that the case for you?

Comment: yeah the data is sorted (all the names are sorted)

Comment: Disks are far better at sequential access than at random one.  And the basic unit is the sector or even a cluster of sectors.  Are you sure that a binary search is warranted.  Look for B-Trees for a data structure better suited for the task if you really have enough data that gulping everything in memory isn't a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

You know the number of elements and the data structure allows you to do a random access to any element:

```
const int middleOffset = ((int*)foo)[num/2];
string middleName = ((char*)foo)+middleOffset;
```

Comment: but that would make middle always a const?

Comment: The middle isn't changed until the data is reloaded, so I put it as const, but if you want to be able to reassign it within the search algorithm, skip the `const`.

Answer (score 1):

The functions `seekg` and `tellg` of C++ file streams will allow you to navigate though the file.